# Zend Framework SQL Injection protection

Tags: sql, zend-framework

I'm looking at some Zend Framework code a developer I'm working with is using, and in it I see the following:

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($DB);
$sql = $select->where("id ='".$id."'");
```

Now, $id is not sanitized anywhere, and I was under the impression that you're only protected from injection via Zend if you use placeholders -- this string is vulnerable, I thought.

The author of the code claims zend takes care of it even in this case, although I can't find in the documentation where it says so.

Can anyone clear up if this is, in fact, safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The other developer is mistaken.

If you look at the documentation [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) you can find comments towards the bottom of the page that discuss example #20 as being subject to SQL injection if the parameters were coming from user input. Example #20 is more-or-less doing the same thing as the code you pasted. (Although, your code has single quotes, but this of course doesn't make it any safer.)

I have no idea why anyone would disregard the placeholders in favor of this unsafe and less clean way of writing it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the validation here. I'm not familiar with Zend framework but based on what I know it seemed ... wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
$id = 3;
$where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto("id =?', $ id);
```

Result:

```
id = '3'
```

This method automatically adds single quotes building the sql correctly. I think it is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholders, Zend will sanitize your data.

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($DB);
$sql = $select->where("id = ? ", $id);
```

Comment: Yes, I know THAT will protect, but the original author claims his will as well, which I belive is wrong. Just trying to verify.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zend and its sanitation techniques, however the data *might* be sanitized if it santitizes the string in the where method. I.e. it sanitizes any input to $db_obj->method()

Comment: In your case the data won't be sanitized - just pass something like `$id = "1' OR '1";` and look at the resulting SQL query. Placeholders are like variables for Zend - it knows what to do with the placeholders - how to filter/validate them; but when you pass manually generated string - it will be executed 'as is'.